# what is obj and rho in SVM(SVC) training verbose

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I trained a model for classification in SVC which I want to visualize the trainng process so the verbose is set to True. And this is the result I get:

```
optimazation finished,#iter = 200
obj = -315.082675, rho = 3.537407
nSV = 232, nBSV = 199
```

The iter says that the iteration needed for the convergence. What does the obj and rho mean in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*scikit-learn*'s `SVC` [implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) is based on `libsvm`. You are trying to solve the *ν-Support Vector Classification* problem which is defined [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) as the following quadratic program (the primal problem):

[image]

where the corresponding dual problem is

[image]

The *ν-SVC* of a soft margin variant of the optimal hyperplane uses the *ν-*parameterization. The standard regularization parameter *C* is replaced by a parameter *ν ∈ [0, 1]* which is the lower and upper bound on the number of examples that are support vectors and that lie on the wrong side of the hyperplane, respectively, as mentioned [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/nusvmtutorial.pdf).

The variable ρ is optimized as well. Note that for ξ = 0, the two classes are separated by the margin 2ρ/||w||. Here *rho* refers to the optimal value of ρ at convergence. And *obj* is the optimal value of the objective function (which is minimized) at convergence.